# Borel complexity of special unions of Polish spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

Let $X$ be a compact metrizable space and $(A_q)_{q\in\mathbb Q}$ be a family of pairwise disjoint sets, indexed by rational numbers. Assume that the family $(A_q)_{q\in\mathbb Q}$ has the following properties:

$\bullet$  for any compact subset $K\subseteq \mathbb Q$ the union $\bigcup_{q\in K}A_q$ is a $G_\delta$-subset of $X$;

$\bullet$ for any discrete subspace $D\subseteq\mathbb Q$ the union $\bigcup_{q\in D}A_q$ is a difference of two $G_\delta$-sets in $X$;

$\bullet$ for any Polish subspace $P\subseteq\mathbb Q$ the union $\bigcup_{q\in P}A_q$ is an $F_{\sigma\delta}$-subset of $X$;

$\bullet$ for any point $x\in X$ the set $\{q\in\mathbb Q:x\in\bar A_q\}$ has at most one accumulation point in $X$.

**Problem.** *What is the upper bound for the Borel complexity of the union $\bigcup_{q\in \mathbb Q}A_q$?* The first condition implies that $\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb Q}A_q$ is of type $G_{\delta\sigma}$ in $X$. *Is $\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb Q}A_q$ both $G_{\delta\sigma}$ and $F_{\sigma\delta}$ in $X$?*